# Stress state in an elastic half space with uniform constant body force

Tags: elasticity, greens-functions, solid-mechanics

Is there a closed form expression for the stress state in an elastic halfspace subject to a uniform constant body force? I know that the Green's function for this problem is given by Mindlin's solution and the stress state I'm after can be found via a convolution with Mindlin's solution. This computation is beyond my ability so I'm hoping someone here has a reference handy.